# Ehcache update element value without changing his timetolive

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I am trying to set à timeToLive on each element in my Cache to 60 seconde to do that I am doing like this :

```
private void putElementInCache(Cache cache, String key, Integer value) {
    Element element = new Element(key, value);
    element.setTimeToLive(60);
    cache.put(element);
}
```

After that I check if my key is in my cache and if it's here I would like to update the value. To do that I re use the previous function but my element never expire after 60 seconde.

To check that I am using this code

```
while (true) {
        Element element = cache.get(key);
        Integer attempts = (Integer) element.getObjectValue() + 1;
        System.out.println("attemps : " + attempts + " and creation time is : " + element.getCreationTime() + " and expiration time is : " + element.getExpirationTime());
        putElementInCache(cache, key, attempts);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); // Sleep 1 second
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
```

And I never had NullPointerException.

If I made a sleep greater thant the timeToLive I get a NullPointerException.

How can I have my element expire after 60 seconde ?

The goal is to check if attemps equals a threshold and if I can't get element from cache to put in.

My global configuration of Ehcache is :

```
<defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="400000" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">
    <cacheEventListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheReplicatorFactory"
        properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, replicatePuts=false,
        replicateUpdates=false, replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false, replicateRemovals=true" />
    <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory" properties="bootstrapAsynchronously=false" />
</defaultCache>
```

In the console I can see that the creation time and expiration time always change

> attemps : 59 and creation time is : 1466576506096 and expiration time is : 1466576566096
>   attemps : 60 and creation time is : 1466576507096 and expiration time is : 1466576567096
>   attemps : 61 and creation time is : 1466576508096 and expiration time is : 1466576568096
>   attemps : 62 and creation time is : 1466576509096 and expiration time is : 1466576569096
>   attemps : 63 and creation time is : 1466576510097 and expiration time is : 1466576570097
>   attemps : 64 and creation time is : 1466576511097 and expiration time is : 1466576571097
>   attemps : 65 and creation time is : 1466576512097 and expiration time is : 1466576572097

Answer (score 1):

Each time you put an element in the cache, you set it with a time-to-live of 60 seconds. There is no difference between an *new put* and an *update* at that level. So you are always telling the value to expire 60 seconds *after* it was put / updated.

Given your description, your `putElementInCache` method needs to take a fourth parameter which is the remaining expiration time that you can compute based on the previous `Element` you retrieve from the cache based on the difference between `getExpirationTime` and *now*.

Comment: thank you for your answer. If I understood it I must get the remaining expiration time by doing something like this : `Date remainingTime = new Date().getTime() - element.getExpirationTime()` ? I have made this by adding an object as value in the cache. This object contains the creation date and the end date of it's life after that I can compare date now with the date of the end of it's life.

Comment: Do you have any example for updating the cache item without changing its expiry?